# Missing ':user_id' key while trying to show user data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've stuck with a little problem with showing user data in blog I'm writing. I have **profiles_controller** with the following code:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @profiles = User.all
  end
  def show
    @profile = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

following routes in **routes.rb**:

```
get '/profiles', to: "profiles#index", as: 'profiles'
get '/profiles/:user_id', to: "profiles#show", as: 'profile'
```

and following templates:

**index.html.erb**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% @profiles.each do |user| %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p><%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %></p>
        <%= link_to 'View Profile', profile_path %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <p><%= @profile.first_name %> <%= @profile.last_name %></p>
  <p><%= @profile.email %></p>
  <p><%= @profile.about %></p>
</div>
```

I use extended `devise` `User` model with added attrs as first name, last name and 'about' section.
When I try to navigate either to `/profiles` path, it returns me following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Profiles#index
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"} missing required keys: [:user_id]
```

When I remove

```
<%= link_to 'View Profile', profile_path %>
```

line from **index.html.erb**, `/profiles` path works, but `/profile` path still doesn't. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `show` action in the controller, it should be:

```
User.find(params[:id])
```

Also, the link should be:

```
<%= link_to 'View Profile', profile_path(user) %>
```

Comment: that worked, thanks! in 11 minutes I will be able to accept your answer